# Tensorflow cost function based on binary xor operation

Tags: python, tensorflow, bitwise-operators, bitwise-xor

I am trying to create a cost function that is based on the xor operation of x & y.

x and y are tf.float32 tensors and both have the same shape.

x --> ... --> y auto-encoder network

I have tried doing the following:

```
x_value = tf.cast(x, tf.int32)
y_value = tf.cast(y, tf.int32)
xor_bitwise_result = tf.bitwise.bitwise_xor(x_value, y_value)   
cost_value = tf.cast(xor_bitwise_result, tf.float32)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(cost_value)
```

but I am getting an error:

`ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradient.`

if I try to do the following I will get the same error as well

```
cost = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(x_value-y_value)))
```

It might be the way I am casting is not good, it is possible my understanding of the process is lacking so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The gradients for XOR are not defined. That is, is basically impossible to tell whether changing a value in your parameters will make `cost` bigger or smaller, so the optimizer does not know how to update the variables. If you know how to compute (or estimate) the gradient for that loss function you could implement it with [`tf.custom_gradient`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient), but I don't think it's possible in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I was thinking I would get a numeric value that would be treated same as if I do (y-x). Also I tried the other case where I compared cast-ed values. For example, this one failed:
`cost = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(x_value-y_value)))`
even though this one works fine:
`cost = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(x-y)))`

Comment: Yes, you're right, gradients do not propagate through integer tensors. There is a discussion about in [issue #20524](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20524) (apparently there was a time when they did, but they removed the behavior for consistency). So yes, any loss that you define on the basis of integers is not going to work (unless you provide your own gradient definition, as I said earlier).